# Matrix with basis and dimensions

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I have recently come upon this question and I have no idea how to go on from where I stopped :

$$\text{GivenMatrix}
 :\: A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1&a&3 \\ a & -a^2+a+2 & -4a-2 \\ a-1 & -a^2+2a+2 & -4a+1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

1. Find for every value of $a$ the basis and the dimension for **Nul(A)**
2. Is there a value for **a** that for it there are $2$ vectors $(\vec{u_1},\vec{u_2})$ not linearly independent that create $A×\vec{u_1}=0$ and $A×\vec{u_2}=0 \,$? If yes, find the value for $a$; if not prove it .
3. While $a=-2$, prove that for every $2$ vectors $\vec{u},\vec{v} ∈\Bbb R^3$ that create $\vec{u} \in$ Nul$(A)$, $\vec{v} \in$ Nul$(A)$, $\vec{u} \neq \vec{0}$.

I played with the matrix a little bit and reached this point :
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
a+2 & 0 & 4a+8 \\ 0 &a+2 & -a-2  \\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I have no clue what to do after this can anyone throw in some useful tips or solutions to help me get going? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you  sketch how you obtain this form for the matrix?

Comment: **Hint**:

You can use the *rank-nullity formula*.

Comment: I dont understand (2) and (3). For (2), as stated, this is true for any matrix at all, not just $A$ for some given value of $a$. Just let both $u_1 = u_2 = 0$. Even if you add something to disallow $u_1, u_2$ being $0$ vectors, the fact that they are not linearly independent means one is a multiple of the other, so all you have to do is find a non-zero vector in $\text{Nul}(A)$. Since $A$ is singular for all $a$, this can be done for any $a$. On (3). as stated, this is obviously false (assuming by "create" you mean "satisfy"). $0\in \text{Nul}(A)$. Always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first quesion I get the matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & a & 3\\
0 & a+2 & -(a+2)\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
by $-R_1 + -R_2 + R_3 \Rightarrow R_3$ and $-aR_1 +R_2 \Rightarrow R_2$.

If $a=-2$ then

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
-1&-2&3&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

and $x=-2y+3z$ gives the vector $\begin{pmatrix}
-2y+3z\\
y \\
z 
\end{pmatrix}=y\begin{pmatrix}
-2\\
1 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}+z\begin{pmatrix}
3\\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$ and

$dim($Nul$(A))=2.$

If $a\neq-2$ then you can divide $R_2$ by $a+2$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & a & 3\\
0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{-aR_2 + R_1 \Rightarrow R_1}\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 3+a\\
0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

$x=(3+a)z$ and $y=z$ gives the vector $\begin{pmatrix}
(3+a)z\\
z \\
z
\end{pmatrix}=z\begin{pmatrix}
3+a\\
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$ and $dim($Nul$(A))=1.$

You cannot divide rows by zero so you need to split it into two cases, $a+2=0$ and $a+2 \neq 0$ and then see what happens.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!